# Why are custom leaflet controls added as upper and lower case?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am looking at the Extending Leaflet documentation for adding [custom controls](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html#controls).

It contains this code snippet as an example of adding a simple watermark control:

```
L.Control.Watermark = L.Control.extend({
    onAdd: function(map) {
        var img = L.DomUtil.create('img');

        img.src = '../../docs/images/logo.png';
        img.style.width = '200px';

        return img;
    },

    onRemove: function(map) {
        // Nothing to do here
    }
});

L.control.watermark = function(opts) {
    return new L.Control.Watermark(opts);
}

L.control.watermark({ position: 'bottomleft' }).addTo(map);
```

Why is the control assigned to both uppercase (`L.Control.Watermark`) and lowercase `L.control.watermark` variables? Is this a common convention when extending JavaScript libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the tutorial named [Extending Leaflet: Class Theory](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html), you'll see a section named [Factories](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html#factories):

> Most Leaflet classes have a corresponding factory function. A factory function has the same name as the class, but in *lowerCamelCase* instead of *UpperCamelCase*.

Basically, the *lowerCamelCase* function is a convenience method to instantiate the corresponding class. You'll find plenty of articles on why use factory functions over constructors, [this one](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e) seems quite comprehensive

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is no real convention within JavaScript.

Most OOP languages will have classes with the convention to use UpperCamelCase (PascalCase).

The factory pattern mainly saves you from using the `new` keyword. To differentiate both, in Leaflet the former uses PascalCase, and the latter uses lower camelCase.

But you will find plenty other JS libraries that use PascalCase for their factory (most of the time they do not supply an equivalent class in their API though).

For more insight on the convention chosen for Leaflet, you can have a look at [Leaflet/Leaflet #1430](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/1430) (it was far from being a clear cut).