# Why am I getting the TypeError: L.Control.Draw is not a constructor error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I'm writing a code for leaflet maps with the freedraw plugin. Currently, I'm trying to add options menu to edit drawn shapes. But suddenly I've encountered this error:

TypeError: L.Control.Draw is not a constructor

Not only I don't know how should I fix this but I have no idea why this error occurs in the first place.

I've tried looking around the internet including stack overflow and there wasn't any solution...

Does anyone know what's this error about and how should I fix it?

I've tried adding this into my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.css"/> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>

var map = L.map('mapid', { drawControl: true }).setView([25, 25], 2);
```

That didn't seem to do anything else than just giving me another error L is not defined. I've changed the numbers to the actual versions that raised the error described above. The actual link is for old versions which worked but I'm curious about other issues this could raise. Even console warned me about that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    />

    <script
            src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js">
    </script>
    <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.freedraw/2.0.1/leaflet-freedraw.web.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

```css
<style>
    #mapid{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
```

```js
<script>
    var map = L.map('mapid', { drawControl: true }).setView([50.100500, 14.395497], 18);

    L.tileLayer('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
        ext: 'png',
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Wikimedia maps | Map data &copy; <a target="_blank" href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OSM contributors</a>'
    }).addTo(this.map);

    var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(editableLayers);

    var MyCustomMarker = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            shadowUrl: null,
            iconAnchor: new L.Point(12, 12),
            iconSize: new L.Point(24, 24),
            iconUrl: 'link/to/image.png'
        }
    });

    var options = {
        position: 'topright',
        draw: {
            polyline: {
                shapeOptions: {
                    color: '#f357a1',
                    weight: 10
                }
            },
            polygon: {
                allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
                drawError: {
                    color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
                    message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
                },
                shapeOptions: {
                    color: '#bada55'
                }
            },
            circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
            rectangle: {
                shapeOptions: {
                    clickable: false
                }
            },
            marker: {
                icon: new MyCustomMarker()
            }
        },
        edit: {
            featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
            remove: false
        }
    };

    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(options);
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;

        if (type === 'marker') {
            layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
        }

        editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
    });
</script>
```

```html
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are custom leaflet controls added as upper and lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657310/why-are-custom-leaflet-controls-added-as-upper-and-lower-case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you try using Leaflet [Freedraw](https://github.com/Wildhoney/Leaflet.FreeDraw) plugin with the API of [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) plugin.

Choose one or the other (from your comments, sounds like you need freedraw feature) and stick its API and documentation.

Comment: Oh wow, so these plugins are separate. Oh, I didn't know that thx for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You find below the rectified code:

what you need is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    />

    <script
            src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js">
    </script>
    <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.freedraw/2.0.1/leaflet-freedraw.web.js">
    </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mapid"></div>
<style>
    #mapid{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var map = L.map('mapid', { drawControl: true }).setView([50.100500, 14.395497], 18);

    L.tileLayer('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
        ext: 'png',
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Wikimedia maps | Map data &copy; <a target="_blank" href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OSM contributors</a>'
    }).addTo(this.map);

    var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(editableLayers);

    var MyCustomMarker = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            shadowUrl: null,
            iconAnchor: new L.Point(12, 12),
            iconSize: new L.Point(24, 24),
            iconUrl: 'link/to/image.png'
        }
    });

    var options = {
        position: 'topright',
        draw: {
            polyline: {
                shapeOptions: {
                    color: '#f357a1',
                    weight: 10
                }
            },
            polygon: {
                allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
                drawError: {
                    color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
                    message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
                },
                shapeOptions: {
                    color: '#bada55'
                }
            },
            circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
            rectangle: {
                shapeOptions: {
                    clickable: false
                }
            },
            marker: {
                icon: new MyCustomMarker()
            }
        },
        edit: {
            featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
            remove: false
        }
    };

    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(options);
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;

        if (type === 'marker') {
            layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
        }

        editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it OK?

Comment: Would be much more helpful that you explain the difference in the code and why you think it would solve the issue, especially given the fact that your answer contains a lot of OP's code.

Comment: you have to add this two lines to your code: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: I already tried adding the two links into my project. And It works. But the version is outdated for my requirements. The old version had a "click to create point" method. The current version has a pure hand drawing experience. But it seems like the menu isn't working with the latest version anymore. Anyway thanks for your help and if you have any new ideas share it with me.