# how to pass data with rectangle in leaflet js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In Leaflet, is it possible to pass data with a L.rectangle?

For a CircleMarker I do this like:

```
customCircleMarker = L.CircleMarker.extend({
    options: {
        event_ID: 0,
        event_type: 0,
        event_time: 0.0,
        pa_mag: 0.0
    }
});
```

I tried unsuccessfully to do similar with a rectangle:

```
customRectangle = L.rectangle.extend({  
    options: {
        name: '',
        id: 0
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are custom leaflet controls added as upper and lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657310/why-are-custom-leaflet-controls-added-as-upper-and-lower-case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write `L.Rectangle` with uppercase

```
customRectangle = L.Rectangle.extend({  
    options: {
        name: '',
        id: 0
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million!  I was confused as to why CircleMarker was upper case and rectangle lower case.