# adding a polyline to a map gets me a "script error"

Tags: leaflet

I tried to add a polyline to a map by doing `L.Polyline([[30.20449, -98.48831], [30.73711, -96.99966]]).addTo(map)` and `L.Polyline([L.LatLng(30.20449, -98.48831), L.LatLng(30.73711, -96.99966)]).addTo(map)` and both give me a "Script error" error.

Here's the code on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/e73qmghu/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either the Leaflet factory form `L.polyline()` (note the lower case "p"), or the class form with `new` keyword `new L.Polyline` (note the upper case "P").

See also [Why are custom leaflet controls added as upper and lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657310/why-are-custom-leaflet-controls-added-as-upper-and-lower-case) for more explanations.